# Override design support library behaviour

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-snackbar

I am trying to dismiss a `Snackbar` when a condition is satisfied.

```
snackbar.setAction("Retry", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(isConnected(getApplicationContext())){
                    toggleButtonsState(true);
                    snackbar.dismiss();
                } else {
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            }
        });
        snackbar.show();
```

However, the `Snackbar` implementation do automatic dismiss of it when the action is clicked.

```
public Snackbar setAction(CharSequence text, final OnClickListener listener) {
    TextView tv = this.mView.getActionView();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(text) && listener != null) {
        tv.setVisibility(0);
        tv.setText(text);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onClick(view);
                Snackbar.this.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } else {
        tv.setVisibility(8);
        tv.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)null);
    }

    return this;
}
```

Generally, is there a way to modify a compiled gradle library so as to cope with my needs. ie. to remove this line `Snackbar.this.dismiss();`. I know I can search for the source and put in in libs folder and then I can modify it but is there a way to do so rather than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't because `Snackbar` class is final and cannot override methods so it's behavior.

What you can try, is setting `View.OnTouchListener` to `Snackbar` view and prevent it getting any touch events only for the action view. I'm not sure if `snackBar.getView()` returns whole snackbar including the action views.

```
snackBar.getView().setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event){
         if(v instanceof Button) {
            //This is the Action view event, do your logic.
             if(isConnected(getApplicationContext())){
                    toggleButtonsState(true);
                 return false;
              }
             return true;
         }
         //not action view, proceed normally
         return false;
      });
```